# What is the best container for an integration/pipeline system written with Camel?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, apache-karaf, application-server

I know the question is very general and the answer is too biased to the scale, scope, type, etc. of the the target system. Hence, actually I want to know what is the pros and cons of using various containers such as `spring-boot`, `single-main`, `karaf`, etc. and also when/why I should to use a container for such a system.

In our previous project my colleagues used `apacha-karaf` but they had a lot of troubles such as building the project, settings to allow components export `jmx`, poor documentation, etc. with it. Since the current system is a spring-based application maybe using `spring-boot` makes more sense. Any thoughts?

Comment: Flagged as opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

The main questions you have to ask is what are your requirements regarding:

1. How many integration (micro?)services you will have to support?
2. Will you need to support independent configuration of these services?
3. Will you need to support independent branching/versioning of these services?
4. Will you need to have "hot deployment" (i.e. deploying/ updating/ re-configuring one does not inherently affects the operation of the others) of these services?

If the answer is yes to all, then you have two main alternatives:

1. Go the JBoss Fuse way (RedHat branded version of Apache Karaf). This means that each of your integration (micro)services will be an OSGi bundle in Fuse.
2. Go with a non OSGi container, but in this case in order to satisfy your requirements you need another layer of managing the life-cycle of your services. E.g. you can take a look at Fabric8 (https://fabric8.io/).

This will mean that you will ideally have one (micro)service per Docker container (instead of a micro-service per OSGi bundle) and Fabric8 will provide you will the Web UI (plus many other tools, like Kubernetes commands, maven commands) to manage the deployment of your service to a Docker container. As a result, a service may be  using spring boot/ tomcat, another one may be just a jvm standalone process or another one may be an OSGi bundle running inside Karaf container, deployed inside a docker container. So option (1) can also be deployed to option (2).

Depending what path you follow you have to be savvy with different technologies, e.g.:

1. Fuse: osgi/ Fuse container, camel, maven, ..
2. Fabric: your on demand container (e.g. spring-boot/ tomcat, java process, Fuse, python process, scala process etc..), Docker, Kubernetes, Fabric8, OpenShift, maven, ..

Hope this help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use the java dsl of Camel together and deploy it inside apache-karaf wrapped inside a docker container. The key is to use feature descriptors and a maven repository. Then you can create custom distributions of a camel project which are loaded in your karaf distribution. This means you can work towards a really cool microservice approach where services are deployed as individual docker containers.

The biggest difficult was getting the custom distribution of Karaf working. Once that was done the rest was pretty ok. I don't use spring so can't speak about spring-boot.

Inside Karaf/docker you can deploy hawtio and from hawtio do monitoring, see metrics and do all kinds of other stuff. Karaf also has decanter which has a kibana dashboard and alerting feature.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should totally depend on what container technologies you are most familiar with and what you'd like to do with the Camel application.

I think Spring Boot is best when you'd like to create a MSA application with Camel and you are familiar with Spring already. The good news is that Camel now fully supports Spring Boot: http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html

On the other hand, if you have a preference to the classical-style standalone approach Karaf would be a rock-solid option since commercial products like JBoss Fuse (https://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/overview/) use Karaf as the primary container. Plus, if you are an OSGi lover then no doubt you choose Karaf ;-)

Finally, don't forget that you can also run Camel applications on a JEE application container. Basically you can package them as `.war` and deploy them to any JEE container, but it should be worth noting that WildFly has an extended integration support for Camel: http://wildfly-extras.github.io/wildfly-camel/ With the WildFly-Camel subsystem you can deploy Camel applications as simple `.jar` as you do on Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have the same question, here is my conclusion:

Karaf
  pros:
     1. OSGI based, hot deploy and support multiple version.
     2. Maven support, can continuously deploy from maven repo.
  Cons:
     1. Legacy jars are not support OSGI, need to recreate the jars
     2. Dependency conflicts are really hell.
     3. Split functions into bundles, it will take more time to develop and test.

Spring Boot
  pros:
     1. Spring is like a glue, can integration different libraries easily.
     2. Spring boot make it much easier to startup, develop and test efficiently.
     3. Spring boot + docker, will make the deployment much easier in cloud environment

cons:
     1. If you want to support multiple version at same time, need double your infra.

So my suggestion is to use camel in Spring boot. My architecture design is like Spring Boot + Camel + Docker + Consul + Registrator